# Break keydown event for div movement with different keydown event jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events, keydown

I've written a script that moves a div with the arrow keys. This works as I want with the only exception that it only switches to a new direction if there was a `keyup` before the immediately following `keydown` event.

In other words, the user cannot change directions as without releasing all keys briefly.

This is my code for the "down" and "right" movement:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
count++;
if(count < 2){
    switch(code){
    case 39:
        right();
        break
    case 40:
        down();     
        break
    }
}
}).keyup(   function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    count = 0
    if(code == 37 || code == 38 || code == 39 || code == 40){
        cancelAnimationFrame(animationframeID);
    }
})


//movement functions
function down(){
  animationframeID = requestAnimationFrame(down);
  $("#player").css({
    top: "+=5"
  })
}
 function right(){
  animationframeID = requestAnimationFrame(right);
  $("#player").css({
    left: "+=5"
  })
}
```

How can I change this script to allow a direction change to the `right` if the user is still pressing `down`? I tried to change the `keyup` to a `keydown` but that makes the movement of the div less smooth.